# Convert word to phonetic pronunciation with Sphinx4

Tags: java, cmusphinx, phonetics, phoneme

I am trying to achieve English words to Phoneme word translation to create a language model for CMUSphinx. Now I am using the following tool to achieve the word translation [link](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html)

For example if I give a text file as input with the following word it  would get translated as follows

```
NAMASTE N AH M EY S T
```

But I want to do this on the fly dynamically using Java. Are there any API or libraries out there to achieve this.I do not want to reinvent the wheel.Or some other programming language which has libraries  I could use.

Answer (score 0):

CMUSphinx can do itself. You can download [g2p model](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/G2P%20Models/en_us_nostress.tar.gz/download) and configure the dictionary use.

Just for conversion you can use G2PConverter class:

```
G2PConverter converter = new G2PConverter("model.fst.ser")
converter.init()
ArrayList<Path> = converter.phoneticize(word,1);
```

Alternatively you can just force dictionary to create missing pronunciation.

Comment: Thank you I will look into it when I get back home and would let you know.